# How to display an image (which is transparent) on top of another image using CSS

Tags: css, html

[image]I need to display a screensaver on browser. The screensaver should contain 2 parts as static image and moving image. Moving image has some buildings and it is transparent in the remaining area (262 x 192) where buildings are not present. The code is as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%
            }
            #bgimg {
                background-image: url("background/background2.jpeg");
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #bdgimg {
                background-image: url("buildings/bdg2.jpeg");
                opacity: 0.5;
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                bottom: 0px;
                left : 0px;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bgimg">
        </div>
        <div id="bdgimg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second image is getting displayed. But in place of transparent area, some color is getting displayed instead of being transparent. I tried with different opacity vales but no use. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: When I use your code with placeholder images, it works as expected. My guess is your image has an unexpected color in it or there is something else going on outside the information given.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelElliott. I tried with different images but no image is working. Not sure why it is not displaying transparent. I copy pasted all the code which I was trying.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and edit your comment to contain it?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelElliott. I added the screenshot in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you, add the below property to your css

```
#bdgimg {
   background-color:transparent;
}
```

As it is also working fine without this, there may be some other problem with your image.

**EDIT** 
Here is a demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moving Screen Saver</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%
            }
            #bgimg {
                background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg");
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #bdgimg {
                background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/05/09/12/business-2998905_960_720.png");
                opacity: 1;
                position: absolute;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                bottom: 0px;
                left : 0px;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bgimg">
        </div>
        <div id="bdgimg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ash. I tried with different images but no image is working. Not sure why it is not displaying transparent. I copy pasted all the code which I was trying.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share a demo of your page if possible.

Comment: I added screenshot in my question.

Comment: I think you are not using '.png' image file that's the problem. Please convert it into png format.

Comment: I am using .jpeg file. Ca't we use jpeg files?

Comment: jpg does not support transparency.

Comment: Not sure. Because I tried with .png also. But not working.

Comment: I will suggest you to use photoshop to extract the building image from the .jpg file and then save it as .png file. Converting directly to png will not help you.

Comment: I tried completely different .png files. I didn't convert .jpeg files to .png files.

Comment: I tried with different png image and started working. May be the files I tried are wrong.